# React Styled Components generating excessive css

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Take the following example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Ball = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(peachpuff 0% 8%, rgb(243, 169, 105) 10% 55%, rgb(192, 125, 66) 57% 100%) no-repeat;
  background-size: 150% 150%;
  background-position: center;
  background-position-x: 87%;
  background-position-y: 87%;
`;

const SmallBall = styled(Ball)`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
`;

export default () => (
  <>
    <Ball name="Ball"></Ball>
    <SmallBall name="SmallBall"></SmallBall>
  </>
)
```

Here's the markup that's being generated:
[image: generated image showing hashed classes of each element]

If I were to write out the CSS I'd expect to be generated, it'd probably look something like this:

```
.sc-cHGsZl {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(peachpuff 0% 8%, rgb(243, 169, 105) 10% 55%, rgb(192, 125, 66) 57% 100%) no-repeat;
  background-size: 150% 150%;
  background-position: center;
  background-position-x: 87%;
  background-position-y: 87%;
}

.sc-cHGsZl.bmZbgS {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Instead what's generated is:

[image: Generated styles for ball component]

and

[image: Generated styles for small ball component]

How can I get styled-components to output more concise CSS where common properties are grouped and not unnecessarily repeated?

Comment: Which version of the styled-components dependency are you using?

Comment: @Bonnie I'm using v4.3.2

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you were using the very latest. This seems like the sort of thing they would improve upon when going to a new version. Thank you for answering this question, because I've had the same concerns.

Comment: For a more egregious example, remove the additional width and height properties from SmallBall, leaving the exact same properties, two identically styled elements, but two different classes and twice the CSS.

Comment: I did some further experimentation and found that going back to v3.4.10 of styled-components seems to fix this issue and generate the CSS as expected. I suspect this is a bug in version 4+ and have raised an issue on the styled-components repo. @Bonnie

Answer (score 0):

You can add classNames in styled-component.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Ball = styled.div.attrs({ className: "ball" })`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(peachpuff 0% 8%, rgb(243, 169, 105) 10% 55%, rgb(192, 125, 66) 57% 100%) no-repeat;
  background-size: 150% 150%;
  background-position: center;
  background-position-x: 87%;
  background-position-y: 87%;
`;

const SmallBall = styled(Ball).attrs({ className: "small-ball" })`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
`;

export default () => (
  <>
    <Ball name="Ball"></Ball>
    <SmallBall name="SmallBall"></SmallBall>
  </>
)
```

Comment: This adds the classes to the generated markup but doesn't actually use the classes to apply the styles, nor does it fix the problem of the repeated properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler approach would be to make a reusable and flexible component that you can change via passing in properties OR by using style overrides (also, it appears like [this issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1546#issuecomment-432861330) was reported back in 2018). While it doesn't solve the duplicate class issue, it at least mitigates it.

Working example:

[image: Edit Reuseable Styled Components]

---

**components/Ball/index.js**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export default styled.div`
  width: ${({ width }) => width || "100px"};
  height: ${({ height }) => height || "100px"};
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(
      peachpuff 0% 8%,
      rgb(243, 169, 105) 10% 55%,
      rgb(192, 125, 66) 57% 100%
    )
    no-repeat;
  background-size: 150% 150%;
  background-position: center;
  background-position-x: 87%;
  background-position-y: 87%;
`;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Ball, Container } from "./components";

const App = () => (
  <Container>
    <Ball height="50px" width="50px" />
    <Ball />
    <Ball style={{ height: 200, width: 200 }} />
  </Container>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

---

Ball # 1

[image]

---

Ball # 2

[image]

---

Ball # 3

[image]